# Is it damaging to drain an Eaton HS Supercapacitor below its minimum working voltage?

Tags: capacitor, supercapacitor

I have a Eaton HS Supercapacitor that is rated at a maximum of 3.8V, but I noticed on the data sheet there is a "Minimum working voltage 2.2 V". Will using the capacitor to power a boost converter that will drain it below 2.2V be damaging to the cap?

https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/87/Eaton_supercapacitor-hybrid-cylindrical-cells-data-1847238.pdf

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Eaton HS model is not a regular supercapacitor, but it is a hybrid supercapacitor.

It is a hybrid of regular supercapacitor and lithium-ion cell.

So same restrictions apply due to the lithium-ion cell technogy - the lithium-ion part of the hybrid capacitor will get damaged when it is discharged below safe voltage.

Comment: Oh cool! That makes sense! How should I perform undercurrent protection for use with a boost converter?

Comment: According to manufacturer, a cell management circuit is suggested, to stop discharging below 2.2V.

Comment: Thank you! I'll research cell management circuits

Comment: There is also a small note present in the data sheet on the second page:

__Do not discharge supercapacitors below minimimum working voltage.__

It is a bit unfortunate they did not name it a hybrid supercapacitor in the note.
<https://www.eaton.com/content/dam/eaton/products/electronic-components/resources/data-sheet/eaton-supercapacitor-hybrid-cylindrical-cells-data-sheet.pdf>

Comment: @0laf It already reads on first page with big letters and on every page with small letters in the page headers so it should be clear that it is a datasheet for hybrid cell supercaps. Would mentioning it once more in a footnote really make a difference?

Comment: @Justme Yes, I think having written "hybrid supercapacitors" instead of "supercapacitors"
it would help understanding this Note as a specific requirement for hybrid supercapacitors. No big deal though.

Answer (score 2):

Boost converters have a high surge start current unless you design it to soft start with PWM or choose one with soft start built in.  You will extend the life significantly of the Lithium oxide by staying within 3.3 to 3.7 V

Start with design specs for Zout and Z surge load for load regulation effects.